# How to calculate cumulative probability distribution when the distribution is Trapezoid

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

recently I am doing this question

[image]

I want to find the waiting time P(2>X>7).

I try to do this with:

P(X>2) - P(7>X>10)
=(3+8) * f(2) / 2 - 3 * f(7) / 2

I can get f(2) = 0.13333

However, how can I get f(7)?
Thank you

Comment: $f(7)$ is given by the co-linearity condition $\frac{f(7)-f(5)}{7-5}=\frac{f(10)-f(5)}{10-5}$.

Comment: Have you used the inequality notations correctly? To clarify, you want to find $P(X \lt 2) + P(X \gt 7)$ because your working is not the same?